# Making a simple toast work

Tags: java, android, toast

I have this method which should output a toast at the end but it is coming up with the following error

> Cannot resolve method Toast.makeText()

```
public Guess makeGuess() {

        PegEnum[] data1 = new PegEnum[4];



        PegEnum[] codeCpy = code.clone();
        PegEnum[] guessCpy = guess.clone();

        int correctCount = 0;
        int correctColourCount =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < codeCpy.length; i++) {
            if(codeCpy[i]==guessCpy[i]) {
                ++correctCount;
                codeCpy[i]=null;
                guessCpy[i]=null;
            }
        }

        for(int x =0; x<codeCpy.length; x++) {
            if (codeCpy[x]!=null) {
                for (int y = 0; y < guessCpy.length; y++) {
                    if (codeCpy[x]==guessCpy[y]) {
                        ++correctColourCount;
                        guessCpy[y]=null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return new Guess(guess.clone(), correctCount, correctColourCount);


Toast.makeText(this, "You have guessed: " + correctCount + " Correct Pegs" + " and "
                        + correctColourCount + "Correct Colours", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: did you import `android.widget.Toast` in your project?

Comment: why is the toast after the return?? that is non reachable code...

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code -

1) Did you import `Toast`?
2) Your toast is after the `return` statement, and that makes the code unreachable.